# Finding the value of some coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, power-series

Consider the following exercise:

For a fixed real number $k$, consider the sequence of partial sums $$T(n,k)=1^k+2^k+...+n^k$$ with respect to a positive integer $n$.

If $T(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}a_j(k)n^j$, find the explicit value of $a_{k+1}(k), a_k(k)$ and $a_0(k)$.

I've been trying to solve this exercise for a while, but I'm clueless about it. Any help is welcome

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: I think k is a positive integer not a real number. The sum $\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}$ does not make sense for all real numbers k

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184532/calculate-matrix-operations#comment8674494_4184532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the case $k=0$, which is trivial,
$$a_{k+1}(k) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac 1 {n^{k+1}} T(n,k) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}  \frac 1 n \sum_{p=1}^n\left( \frac{p}{n}\right)^k$$
The right-hand-side is a Riemman sum that converges towards $\int_0^1 x^kdx=\frac 1 {k+1}$. Thus $a_{k+1}(k) = \frac 1 {k+1}$.
In fact, you can use the same idea to get the next coefficient $a_k(k)$.

$$\begin{split}
\int_0^1f(x)dx - \frac 1 n \sum_{p=1}^n f\left (\frac p n\right)&=\sum_{p=1}^n \int_{\frac {p-1} n}^{\frac {p}n}\left (f(x)-f\left(\frac p n\right)\right)dx\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^n \int_{\frac {p-1} n}^{\frac {p}n}\left (\left(x-\frac p n\right)f^\prime\left ( \frac p n\right)+\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right)\right)dx\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^n \left ( -\frac 1 {2n^2}f^\prime\left ( \frac p n\right) +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n^3}\right)\right)\\
&= -\frac 1 {2n}\left( \int_0^1f^\prime(x)dx + \mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac 1 {2n}\left( f(0)-f(1) + \mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n}\right)\right)
\end{split}$$
So with $f(x)=x^k$, then $$\begin{split}a_k(k) &= \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n\left( \frac 1 {n^{k+1}}T(n,k)-\frac 1 {k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n\left( \frac 1 n \sum_{p=1}^nf\left( \frac{p}{n}\right)-\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left( \frac {f(1)-f(0)}2+\mathcal O \left(\frac 1 n\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 2
\end{split}$$
Finally $a_0(k)=T(0,k)=0$.

Comment: How did you arrive to the equality $$a_{k+1}(k) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac 1 {n^{k+1}} T(n,k)?$$ Thank you for the answer btw!

Comment: In this expression $T(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}a_j(k)n^j$, the $a_{k+1}(k)n^{k+1}$ factor is the dominant factor as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. 
BTW, I think I have a mistake about the sign somewhere, if you find it, good for you.

Comment: OK I found what was the sign error (my integral bounds were a bit off). This is now fixed.